# PHP - MySQL Not connecting?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im trying to do a mysql query but for some reason this is the error I'm getting:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home1/server/public/chat/includes/functions/chat.func.php on line 9
```

Line 9 is as follows:

```
l6 $query = "SELECT `Sender`, `Message` FROM `database_chat`.`chat` ORDER BY `Msg_ID` DESC";    
l7 $run = mysql_query($query);
l8 $messages = array();
l9 while($message = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {...
```

database's name is 'database_chat' and 'chat' is the table...

For some reason it ain't connecting, what am I missing?

I've double-checked that the table elements are correctly written....

Comment: You probably have an error in your query

Comment: That means the query failed. Try executing it manually (using phpMyAdmin or command line) and see what you get?

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated, don't use it, but still if you want to solve your issue, try this: `$run = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they are deprecated. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for details. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: @AmalMurali the query that I ran on phpMyAdmin is good, everything is ok...Its the first time I try to run php and mysql on a hosting server, so Im getting the hang of this....

Comment: @user2766367 A good beginning would be to start [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to see if there's a problem in your query itself:

```
$run = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Note that you should only use `or die(mysql_error());` for debugging - remove it for production use.

Also, assuming you've already connected to the database, have you [selected the database](http://uk.php.net/mysql_select_db) before you run the query?

```
mysql_select_db('database_chat');
```

Comment: yup, I've selected the database and connected to it once I connect, I run the code I posted

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, just showemd me what was wrong. Very helpful!

Comment: @user2766367 - if you've figured this out, you can add an answer with the solution in it, and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use error checking in your code:

```
$con = mysql_connect(...);

if (!$con){
   // Error handling here
   print_r("SQL Error:". mysql_error());
   exit;
}

$run = mysql_query($query);

if (!$run){
   // Error handling here
   print_r("SQL Error:". mysql_error());
   exit;
}
```

This will only help you find the real problem you are having, which i am assuming is an error in your query.

**Important Note:**  mysql_* functions are deprecated, use [mysqli_*](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query($query) requires a resource. An example is listed below using $link as the resource.

```
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($db, $link);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die('Can\'t use database : ' . mysql_error());
    }

$results = mysql_query($query, $link);
```

Comment: `mysql_query` does not need a resource. It's an optional second parameter - if it's not given, it will use the most recently opened connection as a default.

Answer (score 0):

in your 17th line query requires a database connection.. follow this example..

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","usernamename","password","db_name");
$sql="SELECT * from db_table'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

     <---- your code here ----->

     }
```

Comment: Why that apostrophe after `db_table`?